# HTCondor Problem with Input and Output of File.sub

Tags: submit, jobs, condor

I’m a beginner for Condor, and want to ask one question:
I want to submit a job using this `.sub` file:

```
executable            = Train.cxx
transfer_input_files    = TMVA/Factory.h,TMVA/TMVAGui.h,TMVA/Tools.h
output                = TMVA-top.root
transfer_output_files   = Likelihood_Classification/
queue
```

I want to pass as input files some libraries such as Factory.h and so on, contained in the `TMVA` directory and I want as output file `TMVA-top.root` and the directory `Likelihood_Classification`, but in this way the job ends up in `HOLD`, and I read that this means that there were some errors in the `.sub` file.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When HTCondor puts jobs on hold, it has a hold reason.  You can see this hold reason by running

condor_q -hold

What does this report?